# Grid and flex layout for a card container

Tags: css

I am trying make 
[image]

I tried to do with display: flex but I'm not having success and I can't make it responsive and with grid area the same way.,

code:

```
const Grid = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 40wh 1fr;
  background: red;
  & div:nth-child(1) {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 5 / 1;
    background: yellow;
  }
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Grid>
        <div>a</div>
        <div>b</div>
        <div>b</div>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Could someone help me how would I achieve this with flex or grid system?

example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-river-d6twt

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-chebyshev-mrylp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Grid Solution

There are many ways to accomplish this. I like using `grid-template-areas` to define an explicit grid and place my items exactly where I want them. From the code below, specifically the value for `grid-template-areas`, you can see that `a` spans both row 1 and row 2.

Note: you have a CSS error:

```
grid-template-columns: 40wh 1fr; /* <-- wh is not a valid unit */
```

I changed that line to:

```
grid-template-columns: 40vw 1fr 1fr;
```

Here's the full code.

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
      "a b c"
      "a d e";
    grid-gap: 4px;
    grid-template-columns: 40vw 1fr 1fr;
    grid-auto-rows: 100px; 
}

.grid > * {
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

.a { grid-area: a; }

.b { grid-area: b; }

.c { grid-area: c; }

.d { grid-area: d; }

.e { grid-area: e; }

.grid > * > span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="a"><span>a</span></div>
  <div class="b"><span>b</span></div>
  <div class="c"><span>c</span></div>
  <div class="d"><span>d</span></div>
  <div class="e"><span>e</span></div>  
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fd7t4x5p/2/)

---

## Flex Solution

You'll notice the gaps in the following code are a bit of a hack compared to Grid. With Grid we can express the gaps using `grip-gap`; Flex gives us no such tool.

```css
.flex {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.left,
.right {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.right {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.right > img {
  width: 50%;
  padding-left: 4px;
}

.right > img:nth-child(1),
.right > img:nth-child(2) {
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.right > img:nth-child(3),
.right > img:nth-child(4) {
  padding-top: 2px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="left">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/600" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/150" alt="">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/150" alt="">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/150" alt="">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/150" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r16dogmy/2/)

Comment: Is it possible to do with CSS flexbox and responsiveness?

Comment: @Momin I added a Flexbox-based solution for you as well.

Comment: thank you very much andy on mobile devices like I was able to leave the container display in column and cards with the same height and maximum width:

Comment: if i use width:100  : https://prnt.sc/r1705z and mobile devices: https://prnt.sc/r170hm

Comment: I can't set a maximum height using vh in the container because everything is messy

Comment: @MykonSpt To keep the answers concise, we try to solve one issue at a time. I would encourage you to open a new question and seek additional help there.